# App launching (and working) fine in Xcode but crashes in TestFlight and Ad-Ho

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

Here's a strange issue that I have never come across before. My app is fairly large one (~250MB) with heavy media contents – very image heavy. When testing and launching my app from Xcode to Simulator or iOS device (on both Xcode 6 and Xcode 7 Beta), the app works fine. It takes a few moments to load up, but once it does, everything works fine. And the most image heavy part of my application, which consists of about 50 thumbnails, loads just fine as well.

However, upon archiving the app and either uploading it to TestFlight or extracting as an Ad-Hoc IPA, the same thing happens: on the first initial launch of the app, it loads the launch screen for a few moments, and then crashes. Upon loading it a second time, the app will load up just fine, however that heavy party of my application (with the 50 thumbnails), some of the images will be missing.

Now at first, I didn't know what to make of it. However, upon the second and third versions, I noticed that, depending on how long it took to crash, the more thumbnails would show up. For example: if it loaded the launch screen for 30 seconds before crashing, it would show 22 of the 50 thumbnails. If it loaded for 45 seconds before crashing, it would show 26 of the thumbnails.

Comment: What are the details of the crash?  Stack trace and exception message?

Comment: Here is the crash log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xv506l577q998t5/Crash%20Log.txt?dl=0

Comment: The log shows that your app took too long to launch.  Have you used Instruments to profile your app start up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the exception code in your crash log, you "8 bad food". Your app is taking too long to initialize so it is getting killed by iOS. You'll need to move your app startup processing to background threads.

> The exception code 0x8badf00d indicates that an application has been
>   terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application
>   took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events. One
>   common cause of this is doing synchronous networking on the main
>   thread. Whatever operation is on Thread 0: needs to be moved to a
>   background thread, or processed differently, so that it does not block
>   the main thread.

from: [TN2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)